# access wcf interface method from client

Tags: wcf

This is one of the classes in Interface file.

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassX
{
    public ClassX()
    {
        ClassXParameters = new List<ClassXParameter>();
    }

    public void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        ClassXParameters.Add(new ClassXParameter() { Name = name, Value = value });
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<ClassXParameter> ClassXParameters { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class ClassXParameter
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

on the client I'm trying to do something like this

```
ClassX classx = new ClassX();
classx.Add("testname", "testvalue");
```

But this .Add method is not even visible.

currently I'm doing

```
ClassX classx = new ClassX();

List<ClassXParameter> params = new List<ClassXParameter()>;
params.add(new ClassXParameter() {Name="testname", Value="testvalue"});
classx.ClassXParameters = params;
```

Is there anyway I can do what I'm trying to do?

Note: I am not sure why some of the text above are in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you autogenerate the client code from scratch, it will generate a new class, which contains those members and properties that are marked with `DataContract`.

If you have methods that you want available on the client, you can accomplish this by putting the `DataContract` types in an own assembly, which you reference from both the server and the client. When you generate the service reference you have to choose the option to reuse existing classes instead of generating new ones.

Often it is suitable to put data validation rules in the data contract classes property setters. Reusing the data contract assembly in the client will cause the data validation to occur directly on the client, without the need for a roundtrip. It also causes the error in a place where it is much easier to spot than if it is reported as deserialization error.

Comment: I don't see where I can set 'reuse existing classes'. I see 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' and it is checked.

Comment: That's the one to check - do you reference the assembly containing the datacontract classes from your client project?

Comment: When I add a reference to the wcf service, doesn't it mean that it references the assembly containing the datacontract as well? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It means it generates code with classes, out of the service description (wsdl file). Add a normal reference to the assembly with the datacontract and it should work.

Comment: I added reference to the dll (I guess thats what you meant), but still it doesn't show the methods of interface classes.

Comment: You have to update the service reference after you've added the reference to the dll.

Comment: wow, that works. I did update before but the namespace is different when I added the dll. When I did reference the proper namespace I was able to see the methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Data Contracts are for data only. Any methods will not be visible on the client.

The bold was because of the "-----".